# Portfolio Categories - How to Change Order in Which They Appear on Portfolio Page (WordPress Site)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, portfolio

I have two portfolio categories - Graphic Design and Website design. All I want to do is switch the order in which they appear. So if you go to the [portfolio page](http://gatewaywebdesign.com/portfolio/), "Website Design" should appear on the left and "Graphic Design" should appear on the right.

In the dashboard, I can see the two categories, but I have no way to actually switch their order.

[image]

In my [portfolio.php](http://pastebin.com/NnMJUMat) file, I don't see anywhere that specifies whether the Graphic Design or Website Design categories will appear first.

Do you have a suggestion for how I can reverse their order?

Comment: Probably because it comes out in the order they're made... Find where you're pulling the data from the database and order them by something. Not exactly a programming issue so I'm voting down

Comment: "find where you're pulling the data from the database" that's why I posted portfolio.php....I was hoping that the order could be changed possibly in the If, ForEach statement but I'm not advanced enough in PHP to know how.

Comment: Also, I just deleted and recreated the "Graphic Design" category but that didn't effect the order in which they appear

Comment: Portfolio.php is the view code, not the controller or model

Comment: Have you considered hiring someone? You've posted a bunch of questions regarding tweaks to this WordPress install/theme.

Comment: I already tried hiring two people from overseas - they both fell through...basically just stopped developing the site even though I was paying them. Ideally, I'd like to work in wordpress development, not hire people to do the job for me.

Comment: @HappyHands31 In that case, I'd start with some very basic PHP tutorials, then work up to creating your own very basic WordPress theme, so you understand its concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(get_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>30,'category_name'=>'js','post_type'=>'portfolioo')) as $post) {
```

Is the closest I can find to your code provided, really, you should be changing the model but ok, this foreach statement will cycle through each one in order, so we can reverse the order in a for statement like so

```
$posts = get_posts(array
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'category_name' => 'js',
    'post_type' => 'portfolioo'
));

for($c = count($posts); $c >= 0; c--;)
{
    setup_postdata($posts[$c]);
    // your code
}
```

For future note, this isn't the controller code neither the model code. You've only provided us with the view code, we can't do much with this but reorder the output. Please provide your EXACT programming issue next time.